# My code won't display sprite SDL2

Tags: c, sprite, sdl-2

The screen is always black. Tell me how to display the sprites correctly.

This is my code:

```
#define SHAPE_SIZE 32
    void aff_map(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
    {
      SDL_Surface *img;
      SDL_Texture *Tfloor
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      int map[4][8] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
      SDL_Rect SrcR;
      SDL_Rect DestR;

      DestR.x = 0;
      DestR.y = 0;
      DestR.w = SHAPE_SIZE;
      DestR.h = SHAPE_SIZE;

      img = IMG_Load("floor.bmp");
      Tfloor = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, img);

     while (y < 4)
        {
          x = 0;
          while (x < 8)
            {
if (map[y][x] == 0)
              SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Tfloor, NULL, &DestR);
              x++;
              DestR.x = DestR.x + 32;
            }
          DestR.x = 0;
          DestR.y = DestR.y + 32;
          y++;
        }
      SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

int main()
    {
      SDL_Window *screen;
      SDL_Event evenements;
      SDL_Renderer *renderer;

      screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Zappy", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 8 * SHAPE_SIZE -32, 4 * SHAPE_SIZE, 0);

      renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
      SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

      while (42)
        {
          SDL_WaitEvent(&evenements);
          if (evenements.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE ||
              evenements.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
        {
              SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
              SDL_Quit();
              break;
        }
          aff_map(renderer);
        }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: No idea how sdl-2 works, but I do notice that you don't use `SrcR` even though you define it.  I assume there's a tutorial for this library, how does your example differ from said tutorial/examples?

Comment: thx for your answer, even if i add SrcR in "SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Tfloor, &SrcR, &DestR);" nothing change :(

Comment: By the way nothing change compared to tutorial :( ...

Comment: Aside from code having obvious syntax errors so there is no way it is compiled in exactly that form, I see no problems. Check for errors with `SDL_GetError` and check for return values of SDL functions (mostly `IMG_Load`). If you still have your problem unresolved, post exactly the code that you use, with error output, your OS setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i find where is my error but i still not understand what's wrong :( ... i add a`SDL_GetError` and this is the error output `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface() passed NULL surface `

Comment: Because your `IMG_Load` returned null, most likely because it cannot open file by specified path, most likely because it isn't in the current working directory. This question gets asked at least twice a week here. Make sure file `floor.bmp` is in current working directory where your binary launches (not always the same directory where it placed!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is explicit.
It says that the "floor.bmp" has not been converted to a surface.
It means that 'img' parameter is NULL.

Try the following :

- Specify the full path to your picture in IMG_Load(), for example "/home/quentin/floor.bmp"
- Check the return value of IMG_Load().